# Building google map v3 polygon path from array of co-ordinates

Tags: php, javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a polygon around US counties. The co-ordinates for the polygon are being sourced from a database and json encoded to be used in javascript. Here is the json encoded array from php code

```
{"Abbeville-sc":[["34.02593","-82.59388"],["34.02629","-82.59383"],["34.03162","-82.5975"],["34.04056","-82.60997"],["34.05677","-82.62081"],["34.06238","-82.62598"],["34.0649","-82.63427"],["34.06788","-82.64052"],["34.07661","-82.64548"],["34.08025","-82.64416"],["34.08676","-82.64022"],["34.09155","-82.64131"],["34.0947","-82.64426"],["34.09827","-82.64744"],["34.09987","-82.65131"],["34.10116","-82.65488"]]}
```

The way I am building the polygon is as follow:

```
    var points = []
    for(j=0;j < counties[i].length;j++)
    {
        var Latit =  parseFloat(counties[i][j][0]);
        var Longit = parseFloat(counties[i][j][1]);
        var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(Latit,Longit);
        points.push(ll);
    }

      var county = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: points,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor:  '#000',
        fillOpacity: 0
      });
```

where counties[i] is abbeville-sc. The problem i am running into is it's not creating the polygon as expected. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your polygon is being created with invisible borders and fill. Opacity works like the decimal representation of a percentage.

```
1 = 100% = opaque
0 = 0% = transparent
```

Set your opacity values to something greater than 0 but not greater than 1.

Comment: it's not the problem. When i console.log(points) it's comes out as an array. May be that's the problem. Can't figure out.

Comment: An array is correct. Here's an example I made with the code you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/85Dhm/. Since you didn't post a complete example, I had to modify it slightly so the issue may be in code you didn't post.

Comment: One thing I noticed, make sure you either specify the `map` property in the PolygonOptions, or call `county.setMap(map)`.

Comment: Thanks for you input. The only thing i needed to add in my code for polygon above was map. It works fine now.